# фильтрация данных pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Как сохранить два условия
чтобы значения из списка удовлетворяли условию sums>50000, а остальные значения не из списка  условию sums>10000 , в одном датафрейме?

```
import pandas as pd
b = ['sol', 'doge', 'axs']
res = {'para': ['sol', 'sol', 'doge', 'doge', 'pepe'], 'sums': [10000, 60000, 10001, 
51000, 10001]}
df = pd.DataFrame(res).query('sums>10000 &  @b in para & sums> 50000')
print(df)
```

результат должен быть такой

```
para      sums
1   sol  60000
3  doge  51000
4  pepe  10001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно записать условия, которые должны выполняться одновременно, через `И`, а которые должны выполняться альтернативно - через `ИЛИ`. При этом у `И` приоритет выше, а у `in` и `not` ещё выше, поэтому скобки даже и не нужны:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(res).query('sums>10000 & not @b in para | sums > 50000 & @b in para')
```

Comment: спасибо, я так понял я должен был это знать до пандаса

Comment: Ну, это вполне обычные логические операторы. Разве что `in` не везде бывает, а так да, такое не только в `Pandas` можно встретить.